# Regex - Allow Alphanumeric, spaces and symbols but CANNOT be only numeric or symbols or spaces. Must have alphabets in it

Tags: regex

How can I write this rules using regex :

Allow :
 - Alphanumeric
 - Spaces
 - Symbols

Required :

- Alphabetical
- A minimum of two of the allowed

For example :

- "abc123--" is accepted string
- "abc" is rejected
- "123-9*" is rejected

Comment: This sounds very much like a case of where you had a problem and decided to solve it with regular expressions and now you have two problems.

Answer (score 1):

The comment that *now you have 2 problems* was a bit malevolent.
Regular expressions are just the right solution to verify such things,
under condition that you know **how** to do it.

A general rule to verify a text for presence / absence of particular chars is:

1. Start from `^` anchor.
2. Put a number of positive / negative lookaheads, verifying all criteria but the last.
3. Put "ordinary" regex expression, trying to match the last criterion.
4. End with `$` anchor.

From what you decribed as acceptable / unacceptable strings, I see that you
have additional requirement: The string must contain al least 1 digit
(because you described `abc` as unacceptable).

So the regex should contain the following parts:

- `^` - Start anchor.
- `(?=(?:.*[a-z]){2,})` - Positive lookup for a letter, after 0 or more any chars
  (i.e. somewhere in the string), 2 times or more.
- `(?=.*\d)` - Positive lookup for a digit, after 0 or more any chars.
- `[\w!@#$%^&*+;:,.-]+` - Specification of what you want to
  match - "allowed" chars, occurring 1 or more times.
  If you need any more punctation characters, just add them here.
  Note that `-` is at the end, otherwise you should have quoted it with
  a backslash. Other chars (e.g. `.`, `*` and `+`) need no quotation
  between `[` and `]` (they represent just themselves).
- `$` - End anchor.

Note that `\w` covers letters, digits and `_`.

To sum up, the whole regex is:

```
^(?=(?:.*[a-z]){2,})(?=.*\d)[\w!@#$%^&*+;:,.-]+$
```

Of course, use it with `i` (case insensitive) option.